# getElement from table data in same row

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I made a web page using javascript and html5. Its like a free-board.

But there are some problems that I can't resolve.

1. Table has selectors and button at first row and others have check
   box at first td and number at second td.
2. If Checkbox is checked, the number of writing will be added to
   array.
3. If I click the button, selected work is executed.

This is what I think.

Then, how I get the numbers?

Rows of table are dynamic so I can't make it properly.

This is code for my selector and execute button:

```
<tr class="taskRow">
  <td colspan="8" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
      <select>
      <option value="delete">writing delete</option>
      <option value="articleBan">writing ban</option>
      <option value="writerBan">writer ban</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="execute">
  </td>
</tr>
```

And this is code of my table's one row.
Table is made by `for` loop

```
<tr class="articleData">
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectData" class="tableData" style="display:table; margin:auto;"></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData"><%=item.num%></td>
  <td class="contentData" class="tableData"><div><a href="/wRead/<%=page%>/<%=item.num%>"><%=item.content%></a></div></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData"><%=item.writer%></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData"><%=item.hit%></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData"><%=item.regDate%></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData"><%=item.goodCount%></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData"><%=item.replyCount%></td>
</tr>
```

One thing I can think is that I make a function for each row and I apply it to on `onclick` attribute.
But this way is too complicated and I don't think that would be right.

Please give me some idea...

Comment: Which numbers do you want to get when user clicks on submit button? Are you saying you want to get the data associated with the checked rows only?

Comment: yes, it is what i want to get.

Comment: Did you get your resolution from other answers? did you try them?

Comment: not yet, today I will try this all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    function test(o) {
        if (o.checked) {
            // add "num" class to your number td
            console.log(o.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".num").innerHTML);
        }
    }
</script>
<table>
<tr class="taskRow">
  <td colspan="8" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
      <select>
      <option value="delete">writing delete</option>
      <option value="articleBan">writing ban</option>
      <option value="writerBan">writer ban</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="execute">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="articleData">
  <!--append the index to the name-->
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectData1" class="tableData" style="display:table; margin:auto;" onchange="test(this)";></td>
  <!--add "num" class to your number td-->
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData num">1</td>
  <td class="contentData" class="tableData">1a</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">1b</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">1c</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">1d</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">1e</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">1f</td>
</tr>
<tr class="articleData">
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectData2" class="tableData" style="display:table; margin:auto;" onchange="test(this)";></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData num">2</td>
  <td class="contentData" class="tableData">2a</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">2b</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">2c</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">2d</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">2e</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">2f</td>
</tr>
<tr class="articleData">
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectData3" class="tableData" style="display:table; margin:auto;" onchange="test(this)";></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData num">3</td>
  <td class="contentData" class="tableData">3a</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">3b</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">3c</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">3d</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">3e</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData">3f</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wonder the meaning of the note,  <!--add "num" class to your number td-->

Do you mean change the class "tableData" into "num"?

Comment: `<tr class="articleData" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectData<%=i%>" class="tableData" style="display:table; margin:auto;" onchange="test(this)"></td>
      <td style="text-align:center;" class="numData"><%=item.num%></td>`

Comment: I've tried this then I can see the console log which is "GET /wList/1?selectData0=on&selectData1=on " Is it right? I think it should be innerHTML data like 47 or 23 as a number data from num td

Comment: Add "num" class to your number td so that we can use `querySelector` to select the specific elements we want. For example, `<td style="text-align:center;" class="tableData num">1</td>`

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers is identity.This is my idea (with jQuery). Hope it can help you.

```
var numbers= [];
$("input.tableData").on('change',function(){
    var number = $(this).closet('tr').children('td')[2].html();
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     //add number to array
     numbers.push(number);
   }
   else{
     //remove this number from array
      var indx = number.indexOf(number);
      numbers.splice(indx, 1);
   }
});
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I've hardly used the jQuery before. I think I must learn about it. Thank you very much! I will try this, too.